# Batch downloading Youtube video in HD (720p)

Tags: windows-xp, youtube

On Windows XP, what is generally a good way to download a Youtube HD video (720p from their description)?

I've tried various web services for such, but always upon finished download, the video seems of less quality than it seemed in original?

If anyone knows some way to batch download several videos, that would be excellent.

All ideas welcomed.

Comment: If you have Python: http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) is what I use, there is a guide to installing it under windows available [here](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/windows.html) and a standalone exe if you don't want to use python available [here](http://www.himili.com/blog/downloads/youtube-video-downloader/)